# Reduce the else if (true) of an if block

Tags: c++, if-statement

well, i just grab this function from an old code, but how i can delete the else if (true) i know that is possible, but i dont understeand how to do this with no affect on the output of fValid. I know that this is an easy easy problem, but i dont figure it out. Regards.

```
template <typename T>
void Set(const T pbegin, const T pend, bool fCompressedIn)
{
    if (size_t(pend - pbegin) != keydata.size()) {
        fValid = false;
    } else if (true) {
        memcpy(keydata.data(), (unsigned char*)&pbegin[0], keydata.size());
        fValid = true;
        fCompressed = fCompressedIn;
    } else {
        fValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That last `else` statement is never executed anyway, so you can just remove it and change `else (true)` to just `else`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the condition of the first 'if' is false, then the code inside the 'else' block definitely executes. **if (true)** and its else statement are redundant. The equivalent of your code is this:

```
template <typename T>
void Set(const T pbegin, const T pend, bool fCompressedIn)
{
    if (size_t(pend - pbegin) != keydata.size()) {
        fValid = false;
    } else {
        memcpy(keydata.data(), (unsigned char*)&pbegin[0], keydata.size());
        fValid = true;
        fCompressed = fCompressedIn;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the same:

```
template <typename T>
void Set(const T pbegin, const T pend, bool fCompressedIn)
{
    fValid = size_t(pend - pbegin) == keydata.size();
    
    if (fValid ) {
        memcpy(keydata.data(), (unsigned char*)&pbegin[0], keydata.size());
        fCompressed = fCompressedIn;
    }
}
```